# Please assist me with creating SQL Script

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, sum

I am trying to join following this two table and get the sum of id #2  from table 1 and join it with table 2

```
TABLE # 1
customer  id amount
Nick      1    150
Jack      2    100
Jack      2    130
TABLE # 2
product   Typ   Date        id
Apple    Fruit  2/19/15     1
Banana   Fruit  2/19/15     2
```

The result I would like to see is amount get picked up for id # 2.

```
customer  id amount  product      Typ     Date      id
Nick      1    150    Apple      Fruit   2/19/15     1
Jack      2    230    Banana     Fruit   2/19/15     2
```

Hope it makes sense,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of **Group by** we can use **ROW_NUMBER()** and **PARTITION BY**.

```
DECLARE @TABLE1 TABLE(Customer varchar(100), Id int, Amount int)

INSERT INTO @TABLE1
SELECT 'Nick', 1, 150 UNION
SELECT 'Jack', 2, 100 UNION
SELECT 'Jack', 2, 130 

DECLARE @TABLE2 TABLE(Product varchar(100), Typ Varchar(20), [Date] date, Id int)

INSERT INTO @TABLE2
SELECT 'Apple', 'Fruit', '2/19/15', 1 UNION
SELECT 'Banana', 'Fruit', '2/19/15', 2  


SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT Customer, id, SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY Id) Amount,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Id) RN
    FROM @TABLE1 
)
T1
JOIN @TABLE2 T2 ON T1.Id = T2.Id
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Selva, it worked out for me.

Answer (score 1):

First find the `Sum` of `amount` per `customer`.

Then join the result to the `table2` using `ID` to get the result. Try this.

```
select * from table2 A
(
select sum(amount) amount,customer, id 
from table1
group by customer, id 
) B on A.Id =B.Id
```

Comment: group by id would suffice

Comment: @Alfons - Yeah, But OP need `Customer` column as well in result

Comment: Yes that did not work and i agree i do need customer comment as well.